# C++ how to access a string member of a list of structures

Tags: c++, string, list, struct

I have a this struct:

```
struct student {
    string name;
    int practical_grade;
    int exam_grade;
    int number_of_absences;
};
```

I have created a list of this struct. I can access all `int` members, but when I try to access `name` field my program stops. Any idea why?

```
int main() {
    string studentName;
    int practicalGrade;
    int examGrade;
    int numberOfAbsences;

    list <student> lista;
    list <student>::iterator it = lista.begin();

    cout<<"\tName: "; cin>>studentName;
    cout<<"\tpractical grade: "; cin>>practicalGrade;
    cout<<"\texam grade: "; cin>>examGrade;
    cout<<"\tnumber of absences: "; cin>>numberOfAbsences;

    lista.push_front({studentName,practicalGrade,examGrade,numberOfAbsences});

    cout<< "elem: " << (*it).name;
    cout<< "practical grade: " << (*it).practical_grade;
    cout<< "\nexam: " << (*it).exam_grade <<' ' << (*it).number_of_absences <<"\n"; 
}
```

Comment: `push_front()` iinvalidates the `it` obtained with `begin()`.

Comment: Since the list is empty, begin() returns the ending iterator value, which remains valid. But then, dereferencing the ending iterator value is undefined behavior.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no. [`push_front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_front) does not invalidate any iterators.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, the list is empty. When you call `lista.begin()` on an empty list, it returns an iterator to the end of the list. Then, when you de-reference the iterator: `(*it)`, you are deferencing the ending iterator that doesn't point to any element. This has undefined behaviour.

Solution: declare and initialize `it` when the list actually contains an element. Or simply:

```
cout<< "elem: " << lista.front().name;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment has already answered it. In code:

```
lista.push_front({studentName,practicalGrade,examGrade,numberOfAbsences});

it =  lista.begin(); // Update it

cout<< "elem: " << (*it).name;
cout<< "practical grade: " << (*it).practical_grade;
cout<< "\nexam: " << (*it).exam_grade <<' ' << (*it).number_of_absences <<"\n";
```